# Report Server has encountered a SharePoint error

Tags: 2007, reporting-services

I'm trying to deploy a report created with SQL Business Intelligence 2008 on a Sharepoint 2007.

I've done this process a lot of time, but since yesterday I receive this error when deploying:

> "Report Server has encounterd a SharePoint error"

I've tried to reboot the machine where I have SQL Business Intelligence, I've also rebooted the SharePoint server, I checked credentials in Credential Manager and everything seems to be correct.

Any suggestion?

Comment: Check the logs when you get the error. And the event viewer on the SharePoint application server.

Comment: @user19952 the strange fact is that I have no error logged in event viewer on the SharePoint server and even in the SQL BI server.

Comment: You should reproduce the error in your environment and then watch the logs to see what is really going on. Do you have any tool for reading logs like ULS?